# Site not loading Static files

Tags: python, django

Django 2.1.15/ Python 3.7.3

I'm in the process of uploading my project (first time I have done so for Django), but I can't seem to get the Static files to load (so no CSS styling on the website).  It works fine on my localhost

My app will be placed in a subdomain (mywebsite/myapp)

The file structure is...

```
website_files
 |--myapp
    |--static
      |- <CSS & JS Files>
    |--myapp
      |-settings.py
      |-urls.py
```

The settings file has the following

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tmp')
```

However, if I make the following tweak, then the CSS will load, but only on the index?

```
STATIC_URL = 'myapp/static/'
```

Comment: Did you add `{% load static %}` on the top of the pages? Also how do you call static files

Comment: I did; it's in my base_layout file - as I said, works fine on my localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to put your static files folder at setting.py file level, and delete from website_files folder, then you need to make this change in settings.py file as follow:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/static')
]
```

Then run the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then in your website_files, the static folder will create automatically.

Comment: Not quite, but know I'm nearly there; getting this error "0 static files copied to '/home/mysite/myapp/static', 121 unmodified.", but I guess that might be because I need to copy the Static file into setting.py file-level first?

Comment: Moved the static files to the same file that settings is in and run collectstatic, but still not working - once again, if I change STATIC_URL to `'myapp/static/'` then I get CSS on the index, but nothing else. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, got it - had to place the static files in public_html folder, so should really look at editing my settings file to point to that file (or maybe I need to place `myapp` in that folder?)  However, for now, it works!  Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry, for the late reply! Most welcome! Also, I am not aware of your public_html folder, if you can show me your folder structure then I can help! And maybe you have not added templates settings to settings.py file. @JimBob